# Pattern matching in ksh script

Tags: ksh

I have a **URL parameters**  in a variable like

`a=44&search=My World`

here I want to do a pattern matching like

```
if [ $a =~ "search" ] ;
then
   value=1
else
   value=0

fi
```

But it is not working in KSH script.

Comment: Do you mean to say the variable `$a` contains the text `44&search=My World` and you want to test is it contains the string `search` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need `[[`  for ksh regular expressions, not the Bourne shell `[`.  Although in this case it hardly seems worth using an RE.

So:

```
if [[ $a =~ "search" ]]
then 
    value=1 
else 
    value=0
fi
```

Comment: To use a regular expression like that in ksh93 one would need to lose the double quotes on the right hand side..

Answer (score 0):

```
found=`echo $a | grep search`
if [ -z $found ]; then
  value=0
else
  value=1
fi
```