# AIX KSH Pattern Matching issue

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

Whenever I run the below script on AIX:

```
#!/bin/ksh
val="TRM"

if [[ ( $val =~ TRM ) ]]; then
echo "working"
fi
```

Error is:

```
test.sh[5]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 5 : `=~' is not expected.
```

Trying to perform a pattern matching. Any advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: you need `val="TRM"` (no `$` in line 2)

Comment: Corrected, that was a typo. Its the second error which is the problem...

Comment: What version of ksh is this? If you start an interactive ksh session and enter `[[ foo =~ o ]] && echo y || echo n`, what happens?

Comment: see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942920/pattern-matching-in-ksh-script

Comment: @glennjackman - [[ foo =~ o ]] && echo y || echo n
ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `=~' is not expected.

Whats best way to check KSH version?

Comment: Looks like your version of ksh does not have regex support. I think the best way to get the version is `echo "${KSH_VERSION:-$(what $(which ksh))}"` -- I suspect you'll see version 88 in there

Comment: @OP: Exactly what do you wish to achieve: exact match or sub-string match?

Answer (score 0):

I amended it as per below and it solved my problem.

> if [[ ( $val = *TRM* ) ]]; then